# How to get notified when Search Center indexes new content?

Tags: search

I have a requirement in which I want to process new entries in real time as they are indexed by SharePoint Search Center. Is there any filter mechanism that can be plugged in to the pipeline for me to able to get realtime alert when a new entry is indexed? Or is there any event that can be fired everytime a new entry appears?

If nothing else works then I will probably periodically poll the server. Any better way?

Answer (score -1):

Search should have an RSS feed. You could configure a search query based on modified date only. This should generally work (except for newly indexed content that is *old* in terms of modifications).